# How can I force Snowflake users to filter results from a table using a column value, like a date/timestamp?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When discussing how to [stop Snowflake users from running `select *`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72892607/132438) on a table, we got a [related question](https://twitter.com/rahulj51/status/1544942765477433345): "*If only there was a way to do something similar to enforce a where clause on the date/timestamp column*"

[image]

So how I can force Snowflake users to use a range of dates when querying a table?

Answer (score 3):

> **Note**: Check [a cleaner solution using table UDFS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72918861/132438)

---

One way to solve this is to create a view over the table. The first row of this view should be full of invalid computations, and a date/timestamp outside the normal range of dates:

```sql
create or replace table mytable3(i number, s string, d date);

insert into mytable3 values (1, 2, '2020-01-01');

create or replace secure view mytable3_view 
as
select 'you need to add a date filter'::int i, 'you need to add a date filter'::int s, '1-1-1'::date d
union all
select * 
from mytable3
;
```

Now whenever someone queries that view, it will throw a descriptive error whenever they don't filter out the inappropriate date:

```sql
select i, s
from mytable3_view
--where d > '2000-01-01'
;

-- Numeric value 'you need to add a date filter' is not recognized
```

[image]

Note that with a `secure view` we can manage permissions so analysts can only get data through the view, without giving them access to the underlying table.

Extra credits:

- Thanks to Lukasz for sharing a way to get [more descriptive errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72901555/132438).
- Thanks to Mike for sharing a way of using [row-level-security to analyze queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72903629/132438) and force policies like these.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner alternative (as [suggested on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/snowflake/comments/vu3krf/force_where_condition_against_a_specific_field/ifbyvjc/)): Create a SQL table function requiring the filtering parameters, and then returns the filtered table:

```sql
create or replace secure function table_within(since date, until date )
returns table(i number, s string, d date)
as $$
select i, s, d
from mytable3
where d between since and until
$$;
```

Then you can use it with `select * from table(function_name(since, until))`:

```sql
select * 
from table(table_within('2019-01-01'::date, '2021-01-01'::date))
```

[image]